# pg_search not working on simple example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I am trying to use gem "pg_search" and it is not working.

```
class ShopItem < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cart_items
    has_attached_file :shop_image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", large: "500x500>", very_large: "600x600>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :shop_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
    include PgSearch
    pg_search_scope :search_by_text, against: [:title1, :description1, :title2, :description2]
end
```

My controller

```
class ShopItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    if params[:query].present?
      @shop_items = ShopItem.search_by_text(params[:query]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 32).order('created_at DESC')
    else
      @shop_items = ShopItem.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 32).order('created_at DESC')
    end

  end
end
```

And in my shop_items_path I have a search field like

```
<%= form_tag shop_items_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:query], autofocus: true,  type: "text", placeholder: 'search for messages'%>
      <%= submit_tag "search", type: "submit"%>
      <% end %>
```

When I am using search I have in browser query like: http://localhost:3000/shop_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=first+shop+item&commit=search

some data from console:

```
Started GET "/shop_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=first&commit=search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-09 03:05:42 -0400
Processing by ShopItemsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"first", "commit"=>"search"}
  Contact Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" ORDER BY "contacts"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ShoppingCart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shopping_carts".* FROM "shopping_carts" WHERE "shopping_carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering shop_items/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "shop_items"
  Rendered shop_items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 125ms (Views: 120.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

and nothing get.
But if I am using rails console: `ShopItem.search_by_text("item")`
it return me an object

What is going wrong?

Comment: What is the value of params[:query] in your controller?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Sorry, I am not understand your question). I don't have defined value in my controller, I am expect it from my search bar in view.

Comment: I know, when you submit the search form what are you receiving in params in the controller action (index)

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon 
it is from debug
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  search: item
  commit: search
  controller: shop_items
  action: index
permitted: false

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Can I somehow trace the params[:query] ? Search return me nothing even if I am asking the correct title or description

Comment: try `puts params[:query]` before `if params[:query].present?` to print out value of params[:query]

Comment: I found the problem. I was using localization in my project. Fixed by params[:locale] with my search query.